# Using preg replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a string like this => BGCOS1>BGSNB1(190MB)_BGSNB1>BGDBH1(180MB)_BGDBH1.
 I want it to be like this => BGCOS1>BGSNB1>BGDBH1 using preg_replace (replace "(190MB)_BGSNB1" ). for this I use:

```
$A = preg_replace('/\(\d+\w+\)\_\w+/', '', $B);
```

but it returns me this value : BGCOS1>BGSNB1_BGSNB1>BGDBH1_BGDBH1
what will be the exact formula to replace this?

Comment: We can only guess at how you want to manipulate the string. You need to explain *exactly* how you want the regular expression to work.

Comment: I just want to replace (190MB)_BGSNB1 from this string BGSNB1(190MB)_BGSNB1....

Comment: @sharvanaz That's what you want *in this particular case*, but you haven't said what the actual *rule* is. I've guessed it in my answer and it works here, but it could fail somewhere else if I got the rule wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since my regex abilities are not that strong I would use `preg_match_all()` instead of `preg_replace()` and then implode the results back together:

```
$subject = "BGCOS1>BGSNB1(190MB)_BGSNB1>BGDBH1(180MB)_BGDBH1";
$pattern = '~(^|>)([A-Z0-9]+)~';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

if (isset($matches[2])) {
    echo implode('>', $matches[2]);
}
else {
    echo "Regex didn't match anything";
}
```

This assumes you want to match all uppercase alphanumeric characters that follow either the beginning of the line or a `>`. If that's not what you want please clarify in your question.